# Clique of size $k$ or vertex with degree $\geq \log |V|$ is in $P$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, np-complete

Prove that $L=\left\{ \left\langle G,k\right\rangle \mid G\mbox{ contains a vertex of degree at least }\log_{2}|V|\mbox{ or a clique of size }k\right\}$ is in $P$ ($G$ is undirected graph and $k$ is a positive integer).

I tried to understand how does the $log$ criteria makes the problem easier than $CLIQUE$. I mean, assume that all the vertices have degrees $<\log_2 |V|$. Therefore the sum of all the degrees $<|V|\cdot \log _{2} |V|$. The sum of all the degrees equal to $2|E|$ therefore $2|E|<|V|\cdot 2\log _{2} |V|$. I thought this fact might help, but I can't see how excatly.

Need some hint..

Comment: Focus on some vertex $v$, and say you want to know if $v$ belongs to some clique of size $k$.  Then you've got ${{\log n} \choose {k - 1}}$ vertex sets to inspect.  Luckily, ${{\log n} \choose {k - 1}} < 2^{\log n}$.

Comment: OK. I understand. For every vertex $v$, if $deg(v)\geq log(n)$ we can accept. Otherwise, $v$ might be involved in some clique of size $k$. $v$ have no more than $log(n)$ neighbors so we should check at most $\log(n) \choose {k-1}$ vertex sets.... Thanks!